# Can we multiply the angle of a trig function under some constraints?

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic, intuition

Here is the basic version:  We are given the functions $\sin{(\theta)}$ and $\cos{(\theta)}$, with a seeming contradiction...  we don't know $\theta$.  The question is if we can find $\sin{(c\theta)}$ and $\cos{(c\theta)}$, with $c \ne 1$ and $c \ne 0$, by using basic arithmetic (and some trigonometry) on these functions.  The rules are that we can add or subtract any number, and multiply or divide by any number, as long as it is not a function of $\theta$, in order to get subresults.  We can also add any subresults together.  For example, we can find:

$$\sin{(\theta)}\cdot \cos{(\phi)} + \cos{(\theta)}\cdot \sin{(\phi)} = \sin{(\theta + \phi)}$$

The question is if we can do this in a constant, finite number of these arithemtic operations.  For example, it may take 100 multiplies and adds to find $\sin{(c\theta)}$, but this is acceptable.

I believe that trigonometry should be able to tell us if we can find $\sin{(c\theta)}$ and $\cos{(c\theta)}$, using these basic rules.  I'm hoping that someone knows a way to do this, but I'd also be happy if someone could prove that this is impossible.

**A VARIATION**

Here we are allowed a constant, finite number of trigonometric functions to begin with, and we have to find the multiples by $c$ as above.

For example, we may start with $\sin{(\theta)}\cdot\cos{(\theta)}$, $\tan{(\theta)}$, $\sin{(\theta)}$, and $\cos{(\theta)}$, and then we would have to find $\sin{(c\theta)}\cdot\cos{(c\theta)}$, $\tan{(c\theta)}$, $\sin{(c\theta)}$, and $\cos{(c\theta)}$.  The idea is that for any function of $\theta$ that we start with, we also have to find that function with the same multiple, $c$, of $\theta$.

*Note that we must always include $\sin{(\theta)}$ and $\cos{(\theta)}$.*

*Also, we only need to do this for one value of $c$, again with $c \ne 0$ and $c \ne 1$.*

Comment: You can find $\cos(n\theta)$ and $\sin(n\theta)$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$ by induction, using the angle addition formulas on $\theta$ and $(n-1)\theta$.

Comment: @Rahul:  You may want to consider the rules more carefully, because I don't see any easy way to get $\cos{((n-1)\theta)}$, unless I didn't explain things well enough.  The whole point of the question is supposed to be how to get $\sin{(c\theta)}$ and $\cos{(c\theta)}$, and we could certainly try to get $\sin{((n-1)\theta)}$ and $\cos{((n-1) \theta)}$.  In other words, we are not allowed to multiply by a function of $\theta$, as the angle addition formulas would require.

Comment: To make this more clear to us: what information are we given? e.g. What is our starting point? Are we supposed to start at $\sin(\theta)$ to get to $\sin(n\theta)$? Or are we starting at $\sin(n\theta)$ and trying to find $\sin(\theta)$? Something else?

Comment: in your given formula for $\sin(\theta + \phi)$, just substitute $\phi$ for $\theta$. Or another thing you could do, is notice that $\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$, after which you could do the rest. Also is $c \in \mathbb{Z}$, or just any $c \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @anonymaker000010001:  Basically, we're trying to get any multiple of our starting angle that is not 1 or 0.  In other words, we can do either direction you mention:  We can start with $\sin{(\theta)}$ and try to find $\sin{(n \theta)}$ or start with $\sin{(n \theta)}$ and try to find $\sin{(\theta)}$.  I believe that the main problem is that we can only add functions of $\theta$, and I don't see any way to multiply the value of $\theta$ within a trig function without the need for more trig functions.  Then these new trig functions would require even more trig functions, and so on...

Comment: @mdave16:  I would prefer $c$ to be rational.  I guess I should add to the rules that we can't substitute $\theta$ into another variable.  Thinking about the problem I have in mind, in fact about the only thing we can do is add and multiply as stated in the question.  But, AFAIK, this doesn't preclude using trigonometry or complex arithmetic if you're careful!

Comment: @Matt: "I don't see any easy way to get $\cos((n−1)\theta)$" By induction, like I said. For example, $\cos(3\theta) = \cos(\theta)\cos(2\theta)-\sin(\theta)\sin(2\theta) = \cos(\theta)\bigl(\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta)\bigr) - \sin(\theta)\bigl(\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\bigr)$.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to consider, say $\sin(5\cdot \theta)$ or $\sin(n\theta)$ where $n$ is an integer, it's easy (just use $\sin(n\theta)=\sin((n-1)\theta+1\cdot\theta)$ and use an identity). However, I think you're right in general. For example, I don't know of an easy way to find $\sin(\theta\phi)$ for general angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ (e.g. like $\sin(\pi^2)$ I think is hard to find.)

Comment: @Rahul:  I think I see where I didn't explain things clearly, now.  We can only add, subtract, multiply, and divide _entire subresults_, and there are further restrictions on multiplications.  For example, we can add $\sin{(\theta)} + 1$, since we already have both functinos, but we can't add _inside_ the function...  We can't get $\sin{(\theta + 1)}$, unless we use the addition I stated in the question.  The real problem here is that we also can't multiply by a function of $\theta$.  Instead, we have to find a workaround to get the desired effect of multiplication.

Comment: @anonymaker000010001: See my comment above... I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: I still don't understand your objection. In my comment I showed how you can get $\cos(3\theta)$ using only $\cos(\theta)$, $\sin(\theta)$, addition, subtraction, and multiplication. There is no term of the form $\sin(\theta+1)$ in the final expression. Or are you saying we are somehow not even allowed to use the fact that $\cos(3\theta)=\cos(\theta)\cos(2\theta)-\sin(\theta)\sin(2\theta)$ to derive our solution? I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: @Rahul:  In your comment you use $\cos{(\theta)}\left( \cos{(\theta)}\cos{(\theta)}-\sin{(\theta)}\sin{(\theta)} \right) - \dots$.  The problem is that you're multiplying by functions of $\theta$, which are not allowed, _unless_ you find a way to rewrite this as an addition.  In the variation, this would also mean finding more results as well.  I guess I don't see how to rewrite a multiplication of two functions of $\theta$ as only additions of functions of $\theta$.  I _do_ see how you find a function of $(n-1)\theta$, but I don't see how to isolate it.

Comment: I see, we can add subresults but not multiply subresults. We can only multiply by... constants? Functions of $c$? Say we fix $c=2$. Then you are asking whether we can express $\cos(2\theta)$ as an affine combination of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$. But this is impossible because any such combination has period $2\pi$.

Comment: @Rahul:  Yeah, that's what I was afraid of.  It was for an algorithm I was working on, and I guess I'll have to try a different approach.  Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an arbitrary real $c$, arithmetic operations are not enough to express $\sin c\theta$ or $\cos c\theta$ in terms of $\sin \theta$ and/or $\cos\theta$. In addition to arithmetic operations, we would also need powers; this also includes radicals (e.g. for rational $|c|<1$). Moreover, for *irrational* $c$ (as well as some non-integer rational $c$) even radicals might not be enough.

For instance, if $c=0.2$ we would need radicals, and even that might not be enough. One way to see this is to use generalization of de Moivre's formula: write a complex number $z$ on the unit circle $|z|=1$ in polar form:
$$
z=\cos x+i\sin x. \tag{1}
$$
We then find that (one of the values of) the 5th root of $z$ is
$$z^{1/5} = \cos \frac{x}{5} + i\sin \frac{x}{5}. \tag{2}
$$
Switching to Cartesian form and raising the latter expression to the 5th power, we have
$$
z = \cos^5{x\over5} + 5 i \cos^4{x\over5} \sin{x\over5} 
- 10 \cos^3{x\over5} \sin^2{x\over5}
$$
$$- 10 i \cos^2{x\over5} \sin^3{x\over5} 
+ 5 \cos{x\over5} \sin^4{x\over5} + i \sin^5{x\over5}.   \tag{3}
$$
Equating the real/imaginary parts of $(1)$ and $(3)$, we get 5th-degree algebraic equations for the unknown values $\cos{x\over5}$ and $\sin{x\over5}$.
Specifically, letting $y=\cos{x\over5}$ and $\cos x= C$, we get the following algebraic equation for $y$ equating the real parts of $(1)$ and $(3)$:
$$
y^5 - 10 y^3 (1-y^2) + 5 y (1-y^2)^2 = C,
$$
$$
16 y^5 - 20 y^3 + 5 y = C.
$$

We know that, by [Abel-Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Ruffini_theorem), the roots of algebraic equations of degree higher than 4th *may or may not be* expressible by radicals. (And, in general, neither the values of radicals nor roots of higher-degree algebraic equations would be reachable using just a finite number of arithmetic operations.)

Comment: +1, I think that this is what I am after.  Is there some reference, by any chance, that explains this?

Comment: i had a few tentative thoughts about this some while back, but perhaps it may be of some use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281134/query-about-the-cosine-of-an-irrational-multiple-of-an-angle

Comment: @DavidHolden:  Thank you very much for the interesting link.  If only I had a way to do infinite sums in the context I am thinking of...  Anyways, you gave me great food for thought!

Comment: I guess any reference for the Abel-Ruffini theorem would explain the impossibiity of solving algebraic equations of degree 5+ in arithmetic operations + radicals. All the more, the solution is generally impossible using *arithmetic operations only*.